# google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have deployed one application in google app engine. In that application i have created three table. Now i need to add one new table to the existing application. is it possible can any one help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using python, just create the new model and save it and the new table will be created and the information saved.  Note, new tables are not created until something is saved in them. I assume the same works in java, but I have never used java on AppEngine.

From the documentation http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview.html:

> Unlike relational databases, the App Engine datastore does not require that all entities of a given kind have the same properties. The application can specify and enforce its data model using libraries included with the SDK, or its own code.

So if you create new properties or tables, they are added, but only to the new entities you save, the old entities remain unchanged.

Comment: i think it's not correct to speak in term of "new table" on Gae.

Comment: It is the same in Java. Need to create a new class (Entity) and save one object.