# Google app engine application

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine

I create one application in Eclipse.

That application contains the coding to create table in Google app engine datastore (i.e) Google Big table.

In that application I created two tables.

My constraint is: after the application is deployed, I want to know if it is possible to dynamically add a new column in one of the existing table.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google app engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2842790/google-app-engine)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. 
For java when you change your code (add new field) and write this instance into datastore - new field will be created.

But all instances you create before will have null value for this field. It can cause an Exception reading this instances in case if new field have primitive type (int, long, boolean).

There are two possible solutions of this problem:

1. After adding new field run schedulled task that will change null value to default one
2. Don't use primitive types